# Copy instances of starRating from one table to another where tables share accountID

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: tblAccount and tblStarRating. Both have a column named 'starRating' and I need to copy the value of starRating in tblStarRating to tblAccounts.starRating for every account which exists in tblStarRating, as long as that accountID exists in tblAccounts. Each table has an associated 'accountID' which I need to use for matching the values up.

I started attempting it like this..

```
UPDATE tblAccounts SET starRating =
(SELECT starRating
FROM tblStarRating
WHERE (SELECT accountID from tblStarRating)=(SELECT accountID from tblAccounts) )
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Please tag the database you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work like that, but it's dependent on your RDBMS:

```
UPDATE tblAccounts 
SET starRating =
  (SELECT MAX(starRating)
  FROM tblStarRating
  WHERE tblAccounts.accountID = tblStarRating.accountID);
```

`MAX` is there because technically you may have many rows in your subquery, but `MAX` would always yield only a single value

Comment: Thanks, I think MAX has helped matters. Plus I put accoundID instead of accountID in last row above.

Answer (score 1):

Please use below query,

```
UPDATE tblAccounts SET starRating =
(SELECT starRating
FROM tblStarRating
WHERE tblStarRating.accountID  = tblAccounts.accountID);
```